# Compare a sub set array with a master array in Mule 4 (DW2.0)

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a fixed elements array as : `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` This will be used as a base while comparing the input arrays (that can be subset of the master array)

I get an input array of various combinations that may satisfy below set of scenarios:

`['a', 'c']` should return `true` — can be sub set of master set

`['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']` should return `true` — no order restrictions and can be same as master set

`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` should return `false`  — can’t contain additional element

`['e', 'f']` should return `false`  — no matching elements found

and finally:

`['a']` should return `true` — can be sub set and can contain single element too, however that single element should be always `'a'`

`['b','c','d']` should return `false`  — all input arrays must contain at least the element `'a'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what you need to do is basically check that the first element matches and then that they are all present in the `test` array.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays

var test= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
var value = ['a']
---
test[0] == value[0] and (value every ((item) -> test contains  item ))
```

Comment: This answer might be correct, but it might not. It depends on whether the 'a' must always be the _first_ element in the subset. The question does not state that.

Comment: Literal speaking you are right, but imagine that the real example is not that 'a' is required but rather the first element is the one that is mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var mainset = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
var subset =  ['a', 'c']
---
{
    isSubset : isEmpty(subset -- mainset) and contains(subset,'a')
}
```